# C++ Standard: end of lifetime

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime

In the [basic.life](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life) section of the C++ standard, one can find the following (emphasis mine):

> The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
>
> - if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor ([class.dtor]), the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an **object that is not nested within o** ([intro.object]).

I am trying to find examples of the storage of the object *o* being reused by an object that **is nested within *o*** (the opposite of what the standard says).

First I need to make sure I understand what the standard means by "the storage which the object occupies [...] is reused by an object that is nested within o". First, in order for storage to be reused, a new object has to be created. Second, for *o*'s storage to be reused, the new object has to be created in the memory location used by *o*. And finally, the new object has to be created in a memory location that would make the new object "nested within o", for example in the location of an already existing object that is "nesten within o". Is this correct?

I thought of some examples, such as:

- union member:

  ```
  union U { double d; int n; }; U u = {1.0}; new (&u.n) int;
  ```
- object created inside array of chars:

  ```
  char mem[sizeof(int)];
  new (mem) int;
  ```

Are these correct? Are there other examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I believe, by "nested objects here" the standard is simply referring to member subobjects here. Since formally, member subobjects occupy the storage of their container object, without this exception something like this code

```
struct X {
    Y y;
};

void foo(X& x) {
    new (x.y) Y;
}
```

Would end the storage of `x`.

Another example of nested objects per Standard (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#4) is a case when one object provides storage for another. An `unsigned char` (or `std::byte`) array can provide storage for another object, if it is created inside it with placement new. This is almost your second example, with the exception that in your case the char could be signed or unsigned.

Your example of unions is correct example of a non-nested object occupying the same storage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I read in the standard what it means for an object "to be nested" inside another object and that is why I came up with those examples. Regarding your example, what if Y was a base class of X, and we "replaced" the Y subobject? It is similar to this example. But what happens then with the virtual table pointer of Y?

Comment: Not char array, `unsigned char` array. The second example doesn't provide storage (why I deleted my answer)

Comment: @user42768, parent/child class to do not form 'nested' relation. Moreover, C++ does not provide a way to replace a subobject which represents the base class.

Comment: @Barry I see! Thanks!

Comment: @Barry You are correct, it should have been `unsigned char`.

Comment: @SergeyA An object **a** is "nested" inside another object **b** if **a** is a subobject of **b**. **a** is a subobject of **b** if **a** is a base class suboject of **b** (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2). Am I possibly missing something?

Comment: @user42768, seems like I was wrong here. Looks like a base class is nested as well.

Comment: @SergeyA I tried a small [example](https://wandbox.org/nojs/gcc-head/permlink/1pF8eaeoZnn7WOVP) and the virtual table pointer does indeed get re-written. Therefore the original complete object cannot be used anymore.